# Certificates - More than 1 serial number?

Tags: c#, .net, security, certificate, x509certificate

weird :

I use this code to find certificate via c# by this code :

```
 X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
 store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
 var certificates = store.Certificates;
 X509Certificate2Collection certificateCollection = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, "the Serial Number", false);
```

So I tested to see by an existing certificate :

[image]

but it didn't worked (as mentioned in the linked question). ( Also tried  , remove spaces , capital etc... - non worked).

But when I played with it a bit I found **another serial location** :

[image]

this time just pasted the exact phrase  `"4e a1 ae 96 ec 1a b6 82 4e f6 23 9a 16 04 1a 51"` and it **worked** .

What is going on here ?

why there are 2 different serial numbers and what are the differences between them  ?

*p.s. , However , not all certificates has the "Authority Key Identifier " , so there's still a problem finding by other properties...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authority key identifier is an additional extension you can add to a certificate which indicates the issuer certificate which signed it. It isn't required because there is already the Issuer field which indicates the subject name of the issuer certificate but having the extension allows to more accurately specify it.

Answer (score 2):

I Think found a solution. ( I can't believe it )

copying the **thumbprint number** via copy+paste and pasted in cmd :

[image]

what the hell is this char ?

So I typed it manually char by char - and all **good**  (+remove the spaces).

But still why there are 2 serials ?

Comment: Ah - that's why it worked for us. We typed it out by hand. Not because we removed the spaces. =)

Comment: @J.Steen yeah. Ive been sitting on this for the last 4 days. can you believe it ?